# How to change the Accounts-UI template?

Tags: templates, overriding, meteor, user-accounts

According to the [Telescope](http://demo.telesc.pe/) example ([source code](https://github.com/SachaG/Telescope)), it is possible to display a custom accounts-ui form (see his [user_signin.html](https://github.com/SachaG/Telescope/blob/master/client/views/users/user_signin.html)) and use `{{loginButtons}}` (see his [nav.html](https://github.com/SachaG/Telescope/blob/master/client/views/common/nav.html)) to keep the other things by default from `Accounts-UI package`.

I am looking for 2 hours how this is possible. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Hi correct me if I'm wrong but I think he just overwrote the default style in his stylesheet. For example search for .accounts-dialog in his stylesheet.

Comment: Actually I want to add a new input like Username (by default there are email and password only). I don't know how is it makable?

Comment: Did you have a look at this? http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_ui_config It's also pretty easy to roll your own accounts-ui using the supplied methods if you want more flexibility.

Comment: Oh i missed the `passwordSignupFields` option. This is what I was looking for. Post an answer and I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure the Accounts UI with [Accounts.ui.config](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_ui_config). For example:

```
Accounts.ui.config({
  requestPermissions: {
    facebook: ['user_likes'],
    github: ['user', 'repo']
  },
  passwordSignupFields: 'USERNAME_AND_OPTIONAL_EMAIL'
});
```