# Override inherent Accounts-ui in meteor

Tags: templates, meteor, user-accounts, meteor-accounts

I want to change the accounts-ui template in meteor. Not only do I want to change the interface part and make it more presentable, but I also want to add more fields like phone numbers, display picture, etc. I have seen this: [How to change the Accounts-UI template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663354/how-to-change-the-accounts-ui-template)

But doesn't the 'passwordSignupFields' field limit the template to just accepting username and email id? How do I add more stuff to it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use your own form and call [`Accounts.createUser`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser) in your submit button event handler as long as you are OK with the other fields being part of the user's 'profile'.  The `profile` field is an automatically published and reactive field that the Accounts packages provides specifically for this use. But it should only be used for data that the user should be able to freely modify (like their name, fav color, etc) as the profile field is writeable by default.

Here is a tutorial I found on how to create a custom login form:  http://meteortips.com/tutorial/custom-registration-form/